# Android Notification not closing on AddAction click

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I used some answers I found here on Stack Overflow, but they did not work. But basicaly, I need my notification to do two things. One, I need it to open the app again when the notification itself is clicked, and I need it to close out the notification when the AddAction is clicked.

The notification opens the app when it is clicked, and this is correct, but when I click the AddAction ("done"), it does the same thing. Instead of the action closing the notification, it opens up the app just as with the notification itself. What could be going wrong?

```
public void onInput(MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {

    //notification body
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
            0);

        //Rest of Notification
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(input.toString())); //BigText
        builder.setOngoing(true); //Make persistent
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent); //OnClick for Reopening App
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_note);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentTitle("Remember!");
        builder.setContentText(input.toString()); //Get text from dialog input
        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        closeIntent.putExtra(getPackageName(), NOTIFICATION_ID);
        PendingIntent closeBtn = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_name, "Done", closeBtn); //Action for the closer
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    //toast
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done! Reminder has been set. Check your Notification Bar! :)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Close app when done entering in text
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add `builder.autoCancel(true);`

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This answer is wrong. First, there is no method called `autoCancel`, it's called `setAutoCancel`. Second, `builder.setAutoCancel(true)` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This code you have:

```
Intent closeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
closeIntent.putExtra(getPackageName(), NOTIFICATION_ID);
PendingIntent closeBtn = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
        closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_name, "Done",
        closeBtn); //Action for the closer
```

puts an action labeled "Done", that will call `startActivity()` with the `closeIntent` (which launches your app). It does exactly what it should.

Users already know how to swipe a notification to delete it without doing anything. Why would you bother to add an additional action button to the notification to accomplish exactly that? Seems overkill to me.

If you reall want this, you could try to use a null `PendingIntent` on the action, because basically you want nothing to happen when the user clicks the button:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_name, "Done",
        null); //Action for the closer
```

Comment: The reason I added the button is because the notification is persistent, and never can/should be swiped away. This is where I am running into the problem, as I could not figure out how to get it working while keeping the notification persistent